# Does the Microsoft Graph API @odata.type include the "#" character?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, odata, naming-conventions

The Microsoft Graph API is based on OData and each object has an `@odata.type`

Looking at the [user resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/intune-shared-user?view=graph-rest-1.0), the `@odata.type` is `#microsoft.graph.user"`

```
{
  "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
  "id": "String (identifier)",
  "deviceEnrollmentLimit": 5
}
```

But the example from [group resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/group?view=graph-rest-1.0) the `@odata.type` is `microsoft.graph.user` and does not start with a `#`

```
{
  ...
  "members": [ { "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.directoryObject" } ],
  "membersWithLicenseErrors": [{"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.user"}],
  ...
}
```

The [Types](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/odata-v4.0-part3-csdl.html#_Toc453752665) section of the OData Version 4.0 Common Schema Definition Language (CSDL) doesn't seem to indicate any standard related to this topic.

**Question:** Is the `#` character part of the Microsoft defined `@odata.type` or part of OData spec or just a convention some OData providers use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wish there was an easy answer to this question.  The OData specification that describes the OData JSON format has the following to say:

> For payloads described by an OData-Version header with a value of 4.0, this name MUST be prefixed with the hash symbol (#); for non-OData 4.0 payloads, built-in primitive type values SHOULD be represented without the hash symbol, but consumers of 4.01 or greater payloads MUST support values with or without the hash symbol.

http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-json-format/v4.01/cs01/odata-json-format-v4.01-cs01.html#_Toc499720587

The beta version of Microsoft Graph supports 4.01, but most of the V1.0 API uses 4.0.  The best option would be to always include the hash symbol for non-primitive types.

Answer (score 2):

***Note**: Marking Darrel's answer as correct since he found this, but answering in a different way*

From [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) you can explore the `$metadata` directly using `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata`

The namespace defined in the schema is `microsoft.graph`

```xml
<Schema Namespace="microsoft.graph" Alias="graph" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm">
```

and for the entity in question, the type name is `user`

```xml
<EntityType Name="user" BaseType="graph.directoryObject" OpenType="true">
```

So, I would conclude the fully namespaced type is actually `microsoft.graph.user` with an alias of `graph.user` but the value of `@odata.type` is `#microsoft.graph.user` because it requires the `#` character (hash symbol) per the [OData JSON Format spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-json-format/v4.01/cs01/odata-json-format-v4.01-cs01.html#_Toc499720587).